# Adding custom include-path folders to LESS.build

Tags: css, node.js, less, sublimetext2

I am currently using Sublime Text with LESS.build package to compile my `.less` files into CSS.

My current LESS.build cmd is:

```
"cmd": ["lessc", "screen.less", "${file_path}/screen.css", "--verbose"]
```

I tried to add some extra folders to the `--include-path`:

```
"cmd": [
    "lessc",
    "screen.less",
    "${file_path}/screen.css", 
    "--verbose", 
    "--include-path='.:/var/www/whatever/'"
]
```

But, whenever i try to build my `.less` files the `--include-path` params seems to be ignored.

The only workaround i found is adding the full relative path on my `@import`:

```
@import "../../../www/whatver/config.less"; //Ugly solution
```

Can anyone point me where i am failing and/or any other workaround prettier than mine's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was a bug out for this. https://github.com/cowboyd/less.rb/issues/13
and there was a similar issue here [LESS @import: Passing paths to lessc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363079/less-import-passing-paths-to-lessc).

Comment: Thank you for the link but I am using lessc with node.js :(

Comment: Apparently this issue is common for nodejs too, so, i am accepting this as the correct answer

Comment: Using GRUNT + LESS : I had a bug with file import because Less uses by default an asynchronous method, the solution was to set syncImport to true in options.